Is it usual to be asked to submit personal IDs in very early stage of an interview process?
After a very quick first technical interview round (basically a form to fill), a company is happy about sending me a link to a platform for the next technical round. Before being able to login, they asked me to provide a photo of an ID (passport, driving licence, etc).
Is that usual at such early stage? What is the safest document to submit? I agree that this is normal to be asked by the HR department once the contract is signed, but what about when no offer have been issued?
The company is US based but I am located in Europe. Also the job is totally remote, ie, based on tasks submitted by customers that I will perform (programming, code reviewing, etc), company will not issue a contract (I will sign a "term of service") but is willing to pay for tasks done on a hourly basis with a contractor kind of relationship. Relationship can be terminated at will at any time.

It's a scam, no one needs your id at this stage

Have you provided them with any Id info?

@DogBoy37 : no ID document, but as they have contacted me from LinkedIn they have unfortunately my real name, photo and email.

Credit freeze time, if that isn't your normal modus operandi. Assuming US or similar. If you don't know what I am referring to, asking SE Money would be a good idea. Be safe and good luck.

Credit freeze may be premature, since if all they have is LinkedIn there is no new exposure; you are not at more risk than before they contacted you. On the other hand, it's easy to do and a good idea generally so why not.

The "no contract" is a huge red flag.

This is clearly a scam. This has all the hallmarks of someone trying to steal your identity. They absolutely don't need proof of your identity at this stage, and reputable companies won't ask for it until an offer is agreed. For the kind of employment they are talking about they don't need it at all. Other hallmarks of the scam is the initial "interview" that is so easy anyone can pass it.
Don't submit any documents. Do not engage with these people again. You know nothing about them, and anything they have told you is probably a lie.

Just for future reference, ID is generally needed when you ALREADY HAVE AN OFFER and am signing papers to be an employee. They do not need any of that before the offer at all.
Typically, most people won't lie about their work rights so that isn't needed so early, and there's just nothing they need your ID for until they need to put you on their payroll.

There can be a time in the hiring process where they need to see a form of ID. They need to make sure the experience and history on the resume matches the person they are talking to. There are  cases where the person they are talking to during the hiring process isn't the same person that ends up doing the work.
The question is when is it appropriate to verify the ID. Too soon makes it seem like a scam. Too late and the company could waste time evaluating somebody that is trying to cheat.
You have to evaluate this request in light of the rest of the situation. You can ask for more details about the ID request. But if you are uncomfortable about this just walk away.
